# Avalonia DataGrid doesn't show all rows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, avalonia

I have a really weird issue with Avalonia DataGrid, basically despite count of rows being constant (200 in my case), it only actually displays less than 200, and count is random.
Every time data is loaded displayed rows at best go up to 170, but sometimes can stop at 120, etc.

I can access all 200 rows from backend, but DataGrid as said above displays always less than real count.

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridResults" Items="{Binding Records}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Path" Binding="{Binding File}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

```cs
public void OnClickCommand()
        {
            Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>(r.GetData(Path).ToList());
            Count = Records.Count;
        }
```

It's worth to add that data is actually there, but scrollbar doesn't allow to scroll any further. I can see a little more on vertical monitor, but buying monitor that long to see everything is kind of problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the setter of the `Records` property lacks raising a PropertyChanged notifcitation. It needs to raise PC when you change the whole collection, instead of adding/removing items. In order to fix it make sure, PropertyChanged is raised:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private ObservableCollection<Record> _records;

public ObservableCollection<Record> Records
{
    get => _records;
    set
    {
        if (_records != value)
        {
            _records = value;
            // if you have a base Viewmodel class, call your custom impl for raising PropertyChanged
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Records)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using default Avalonia method: ```public ObservableCollection<Record> Records
        {
            get => _records;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _records, value);
        }```. Works for everything, and data is there, but as I said scrollbar doesn't allow to scroll any further.

Comment: Oups,  I didn' t read well. Sorry.